# How to know the error associated with the result given by sp.solve?

Tags: python, sympy, system, equation, solver

I am solving a system of equations numerically and analytically. The analytical result, which I found in Mathematica, gives the correct result. The numerical result, found with jupyter through Sympy's `solve` function is slightly different, but enough to give some graphical changes. Therefore, I would like to know if there is any attribute of the `solve` function or the Sympy library that gives me the result with `solve().values()` but also gives me an associated error to that value. So I can have a margin of error. Are there any error attributes for the `solve` function?

Below is the code snippet where I set up and solve the system:

```
k0 = symbols("k0")
w0 = symbols("w0")
h1r = symbols("h1r")
kr = symbols("kr")
wr = symbols("wr")

eq1 = Eq(k0 * integrate_origin_10.y[0][-1] + w0 * integrate_origin_01.y[0][-1] - h1r * integrate_surface_100.y[0][-1] - kr * integrate_surface_010.y[0 ][-1] - wr * integrate_surface_001.y[0][-1], 0)
eq2 = Eq(k0 * integrate_origin_10.y[1][-1] + w0 * integrate_origin_01.y[1][-1] - h1r * integrate_surface_100.y[1][-1] - kr * integrate_surface_010.y[1 ][-1] - wr * integrate_surface_001.y[1][-1], 0)
eq3 = Eq(k0 * integrate_origin_10.y[2][-1] + w0 * integrate_origin_01.y[2][-1] - h1r * integrate_surface_100.y[2][-1] - kr * integrate_surface_010.y[2 ][-1] - wr * integrate_surface_001.y[2][-1], 0)
eq4 = Eq(k0 * integrate_origin_10.y[3][-1] + w0 * integrate_origin_01.y[3][-1] - h1r * integrate_surface_100.y[3][-1] - kr * integrate_surface_010.y[3 ][-1] - wr * integrate_surface_001.y[3][-1], 0)
eq5 = Eq(k0, 1)

sol = list(solve((eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5), (k0, w0, h1r, kr, wr)).values())
```

Comment: Usually solve returns exact results. The code is incomplete and there is no description of the equations or the result returned so I don't think anyone can answer the question with the information provided.

Comment: On top of what @OscarBenjamin said, I'd take a guess that `integrate_surface` is a `float`, which will introduce error.